# Mosaic-Decisions: Different supported timezones in Expressions

Tags: mosaic-decisions

In Mosaic Decisions Flows, I can see there's a system parameter called "$currentTime" which gives the current timestamp. But this is giving the current timestamp in UTC. I want to convert it into CST timezone. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use **Convert_Timezone** function available in transformation node. Below is the syntax for it.

```
CONVERT_TIMEZONE( column_name, ‘Timezone1’ , ‘Timezone2’);

            Column_name – input time based column.
            Timezone1 – the timezone the column data is in.
            Timezone2 – the timezone in which the column data has to be converted in.
```

`CONVERT_TIMEZONE (NOW(), ‘UTC’ , ‘CST6CDT’ )`  -> `NOW()` will give you the currentTime
Similarly you can use – `SystemV/CST6CDT`, `SystemV/CST6`, based on the requirement.

Also you can refer **Transformation section** in user guide for further details on it [link below] :
https://mosaic.ga.lti-mosaic.com/usermanual/Transformer.html